# AuthInfoRequired cups overwrites

Tags: networking, printing, cups, gtk

My problem is basically identical to the following:

> http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=61826

Put simply, I have a machine in ubuntu trying to connect to another ubuntu machine via a network in order to use the printer attached.  There is no problem printing until I restart the guest machine. Immediately it overwrites the printers.conf file (under /etc/cups/printers.conf).
 It always adds the same line:

> AuthInfoRequired username,password

I stop cups and change it to **#**AuthInfoRequired username,password to comment out the command. Start cups. Works great 'til the next shutdown. Then it gets overwritten again.

Googling indicates it may be GTK problem and not CUPS, but I have found no permanent solution to date.

Any suggestions appreciated ....

Answer (score 2):

You can do it another way too.

Just put "none" in the end of the AuthInfoRequired. It expects something like that:

`AuthInfoRequired none`

Answer (score 0):

I've added user and password to the smb share, for example, like this:

```
smb://joe:not24get@winstation/printer
```

and it stopped adding this line to `printers.conf`

If your windows station doesn't require login, just put dummy data:

```
smb://user:@winstation/printer
```